# How to use variable in parseJson function with string objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using three objects in parseJson function and I want to use a variable inside them. How I can merge a variable with the value of one object? Or is there any way to use third object and save variable to that object?

```
var firstQ = "This need to be merge.";

var jsondata = $.parseJSON('[{"q": "Question 1", "p": "Answer 1"+"firstQ"}]');
```

Comment: You can write `var jsondata = [{q: "Question1", p: "Answer 1" + firstQ }];`

Answer (score 3):

This will insert your variable into the `jsondata`

```js
var firstQ = "This need to be merge.";

var str = '[{"q": "Question 1", "p": "Answer 1: ' + firstQ + '"}]';
//var jsondata = $.parseJSON(str)
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, are you trying to figure out how to create a JSON object of this structure:

{"q": someString, "p": someOtherString+someOtherString2} ?

If so, you can do this:

```
{"q": "Question 1", "p": "Answer 1"+firstQ}
```

Don't forget to add a space if it is needed.

Example:

```js
let firstQ = "This need to be merge.";

var jsonData = {"q": "Question 1", "p": "Answer 1 "+firstQ};

console.log(jsonData);
```